# Angular RelativeLinkResolution - Differences between legacy and corrected

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I was reading the angular documentation and I came across this option:

> From the ContainerComponent, you should be able to navigate to AComponent using the following routerLink, but it will not work if relativeLinkResolution is set to 'legacy':

```
<a [routerLink]="['./a']">Link to A</a>
```

> However, this will work:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../a']">Link to A</a>
```

> In other words, you're required to use ../ rather than ./ when the relative link resolution is set to 'legacy'.

From: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#relativeLinkResolution

But my question is what is the difference between legacy and corrected? and what is the use of the legacy option, what use I can have by using ../ instead of ./ ?

Comment: `legacy` (how it used to be) = two dots to refer to same level. `corrected` (now default in Angular 11) = using a single dot to refer to same level.

Comment: Legacy is just to keep your app backward compatible if you rely on previous erroneous behavior

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Markus Pscheidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606662/markus-pscheidt) said:

> `legacy` (how it used to be) = two dots to refer to same level.
>
> `corrected` (now default in Angular 11) = using a single dot to refer
> to same level.

Comment: How is RelativeLinkResolution changed in Angular15?? Since same is not available as part of ExtraOptions

Comment: @Vishesh, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087462/relativelinkresolution-not-working-in-angular-15-but-it-used-to-work-in-11

Comment: @Srk95 Sorry did not understand what you are referring to here. However, that question post has been answered by me only. Thanks